# States in Buttons from LazyVerticalGrid

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have a data class which provide information of a `CarParking` Place. This one:

```kotlin
data class ParkingSpace(
    val id: Int,
    val parkNumber: Int,
    val parkState: String
)

fun getParkingSpace() = (1..4).map {
    when (it) {
        1 -> {
            ParkingSpace(
                id = it,
                parkNumber = 150,
                parkState = "Free $it"
            )
        }
        2 -> {
            ParkingSpace(
                id = it,
                parkNumber = 152,
                parkState = "Free $it"
            )
        }
        3 -> {
            ParkingSpace(
                id = it,
                parkNumber = 153,
                parkState = "Free $it"
            )
        }
        4 -> {
            ParkingSpace(
                id = it,
                parkNumber = 154,
                parkState = "Free $it"
            )
        }
        else -> {
            ParkingSpace(
                id = it,
                parkNumber = 150,
                parkState = "Free $it"
            )
        }
    }
}
```

This information is populated in a `LazyVerticalGrid` through buttons

My goal is:
When you press the button, the Text content of the Button will change into an user name (now is just fixed data) - like saying this park place is reserved to one `User`

There are two separated buttons, to cancel Reservation. I'm trying to show a different content in the `Text`'s button like "Free". I created this `CancelButton` for practicing interacting with the content of the buttons.

This is my main Activity with all composables.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @ExperimentalCoilApi
    @ExperimentalFoundationApi

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ZebraCarPark_ComposeTheme {
                ParkingListLayout()
            }
        }
    }
}

@ExperimentalFoundationApi
@ExperimentalCoilApi
@Composable
fun ParkingListLayout() {
    Column() {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.LightGray)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(horizontal = 0.dp, vertical = 15.dp)

        ) {
            LazyVerticalGrid(
                contentPadding = PaddingValues(2.dp),
                cells = GridCells.Fixed(4)
            ) {
                items(getParkingSpace()) { parkSpc ->
                    ParkingPlace(parkSpc)
                }
            }
        }
        Divider(
            color = Color.Black,
            thickness = 2.dp
        )
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.Green)
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize(),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
            ) {

                Button(onClick = {}) {
                    Text(text = "Cancel Park Place 1")
                }
                Button(onClick = {}) {
                    Text(text = "Cancel Park Place 2")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ParkingPlace(parkingSpace: ParkingSpace) {
    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    ) {
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp),
            text = "${parkingSpace.parkNumber}",
        )
        Button(
            onClick = { },
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color.Green)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = parkingSpace.parkState,
                maxLines = 1,
                softWrap = false,
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(5.dp)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

I was able to make some progress using State Hoisting, so pressing a button will change the content of the button with a new value and all of this stuff. The problem is when the cancel button enter in action. I'm not able to handle correctly the states of the content of the `Text`'s button. I prefer to remove all that code to show you this cleaner.

Project result:

[image]

Comment: Your intent is still unclear after reading the question. If you need to store and change some data in the app I suggest you start with state in Compose [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state), including [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/mymWGMy9pYI) which explains the basic principles. The most reliable way to save during app lifecycle is using view models, info can be found on the same documentation page. If you wanna save data between app launches you need to add a database or DataStore to this logic

Comment: Thanks Philip. What I need. Press Button with Text Free 1 or Free 2 and the Text of the button will change into "user". Now, pressing Cancel Park 150 or 150 you change again the Text to of the button with label 150 o 152 to another value. What I´m doing with this exercise is trying to understand how States works, how you can "attack" the Text of a button through the buttom itself or from another button. The buttons with Labels 150,  152,  153 or 154 are comming from  a LazyVertical Grid, which add another challenge to this, as I have to face how handling these buttons from there.